# Unable to get the value of <a> with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Good day guys, I have a problem, ive been trying get the value with jquery of an , below my code:

```
<li><a id="Prod1">12</a></li>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function SendData(Parameter1,Parameter2){
var actual = $('#Prod1').val();
alert(actual); 
}
</script>
```

When I try to see the value it displays the following: [object Object]
And I would like to see the number 12, which is the value inside the

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3):

Inputs have values, here you are trying to get the content (or text) of a node

```
var actual = $('#Prod1').text();
```

or you can use

```
var actual = $('#Prod1').html();
```

in the above case the two will be identical, but if  you have any tags in there then .html() whould give you the node content, i.e. with html tags

Comment: Thanks, that works, I only added parseInt(MyVar) to convert that text in a number.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're probably looking for is the inner HTML as opposed to the value.

```js
function SendData(Parameter1,Parameter2){
var actual = $('#Prod1').html();
alert(actual);
}

SendData();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a id="Prod1">12</a></li>
```